# how to create dataproc cluster by service account

Tags: google-cloud-dataproc, google-iam

I am quite confused by this document [enter link description here](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/configuring-clusters/service-accounts)

```
Service account requirements and Limitations:
* Service accounts can only be set when a cluster is created.
* You need to create a service account before creating the Cloud Dataproc cluster that will be associated with the service account.
* Once set, the service account used for a cluster cannot be changed.
```

Dose this means I cannot create a service account, which have role to create a dataproc cluster?
For Now, I can only create a dataproc cluster by my own account " gcloud auth login"
But I want create dataproc cluster from jenkins by setup

`gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use a service account to create Dataproc clusters and submit jobs. However, the link you refer deals with running Dataproc clusters with a service account which isn't applicable to your concern.

To create a Dataproc using a service account:

1. Create a service account
2. Assign Cloud Dataproc Editor role
3. Download its json credentials file
4. Configure authentication mechanism:

   4.1 gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=JSON_FILE_PATH

   4.2 GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=JSON_FILE_PATH
5. Create your Dataproc cluster

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create a service account and also need to provide access to the following roles:

1. Dataproc Worker: According to [doc][1]

> To create a cluster with a user-specified service account, the
> specified service account must have all permissions granted by the
> Dataproc Worker role.

2.Dataproc Hub Agent: This will provide access to `act as service account` permission, otherwise provide the following error:

> ERROR: (gcloud.beta.dataproc.clusters.create) INVALID_ARGUMENT: User
> not authorized to act as service account
> 'service-account@project-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com'. To act
> as a service account, user must have one of [Owner, Editor, Service
> Account Actor] roles. See
> https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-service-accounts for
> additional details.

3.Dataproc Editor: This role will provide access to create and delete the dataproc cluster.

**Activate service account**: After providing access to the roles, download the service account json. Activate the new service account by `gcloud auth active-service-account --key-file=<service-json>` . Check the activation by `gcloud auth list`. Set `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable by `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="service-json-full-path"`

Now hopefully everything is ready to create dataproc cluster using service account. Here is the sample commands to create dataproc cluster using service account:

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=<service-key-file>
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="<service-key-file>"
gcloud beta dataproc clusters create <CLUSTER-NAME> \
    --region=<REGION> \
    --project=<PROJECT-ID> \
    --service-account=<SERVICE-ACCOUNT-EMAIL> \
    --single-node
```