# Unable to create a Dataproc cluster with service account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

I am new the Google cloud and evaluating Dataproc cluster and one of the core requirement is to dynamically create a cluster and process the jobs. For the various documentation reads and [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52380621/how-to-create-dataproc-cluster-by-service-account), I attempted by creating a service account and added roles starting with "Dataproc Editor".

I generated the key file and activate the service account

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=<Key File>
```

and try to create a cluster

```
gcloud beta dataproc clusters create jill-cluster \
    --enable-component-gateway \
    --subnet default \
    --zone europe-west3-b \
    --region europe-west3 \
    --master-machine-type n1-standard-4 \
    --master-boot-disk-size 50 \
    --num-workers 2 \
    --worker-machine-type n1-standard-4 \
    --worker-boot-disk-type pd-ssd \
    --worker-boot-disk-size 100 \
    --image https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/poc/global/images/poc-1-5-1-debina10 \
    --scopes 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform' \
    --project poc \
    --verbosity info \
    --autoscaling-policy=poc-auto-scale-policy \
    --service-account=<Service account>
```

I am getting this error

```
{
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Not authorized to requested resource.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
}
```

and I started added more roles to the service account and ended up as shown below [image] and still unable to create a cluster. I am not quite sure what i am missing. I tried command line as well as programmatic approach which resulted the same. Unfortunately i could not able to get enough clue from the logging as well.

**---------- Update ---------------**

I think I missed out some info in my initial question. I have an user account with owner role and was currently using that account to experiment and using that i can able to create cluster and submit jobs. So i think the project has the necessary required roles.

Now I want to move towards automation and want to achieve

1. Manage the cluster using a service account
2. Should able to submit and run the jobs and manage the jobs.

I started both responsibilities with a single account but as suggested i can start having different service accounts.

Comment: What happens if you just `gcloud dataproc clusters list` after running `activate-service-account`? Did you add the roles at the project level? Or is it possible you added the roles on the *service-account* account itself as a target resource? You should expect to see the service account listed as a "member" in `gcloud projects get-iam-policy <your-project>` and *not* on `gcloud iam service-accounts get-iam-policy <service-account>`

Comment: Thank you for the response . 
I removed all the roles and left only "Dataproc Editor" role.  Below is the response from my user account who is a project owner. 

```
/gcp$ gcloud projects get-iam-policy poc  --flatten="bindings[].members" --format='table(bindings.role)' --filter="bindings.members:dataproc-cluster-manager@assorter-poc.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
ROLE
roles/dataproc.editor

```
Activated the service account and tried  ```gcloud dataproc clusters list``` and still getting the same error. I think this should be cleared before i try your big answer.

Comment: Hmm that's strange. For the record, usually when it's the more fine-grained issues with different dataproc roles, and the backend/worker roles you'll see much more detailed errors that tell you exactly what you need. The more generic "Not authorized to resource" message typically means failure at the very first entry point. What happens if you try to use that service-account to do other GCP actions after granting necessary roles (maybe make it project editor again just for testing), such as `gcloud compute regions list ` an `gcloud compute instances list`?

Comment: I also wonder what would happen if you create a new service account from scratch and just try to get the basics working on that, if that makes any difference.

Comment: There's also a neat tool called "Policy Troubleshooter": https://cloud.google.com/console/iam-admin/troubleshooter - try to enter your service account email in there and test it for resource: `//cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/projects/YOUR_PROJECT` and permission `dataproc.clusters.list`

Comment: One possibility if the Policy Troubleshooter claims your service-account should succeed and yet your command-line command fails, is that you may have accidentally deleted the particular keyfile for your service account from the IAM Service Accounts admin tool.

Comment: That might result in a different type of error though. I'm super curious whether the problem goes away if you just create a brand new service account and configure it the same way with Dataproc Editor.

Comment: ```gcloud compute regions list``` and ```gcloud compute instances list``` also failed. Instead of trouble shooting i deleted the created account and recreated and given only "Dataproc Editor" role.  ```gcloud compute instances list``` failed with a message that some of the requests has no permission but i could able to create a cluster without a custom image and no initialization actions and no service account . To be honest i did exactly the same steps before but nothing worked. I will try with different service accounts and as per my final plan will let you know and accept the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanations and providing various options to troubleshoot. It seems some thing got mad yesterday .

Comment: I managed to create 2 service accounts . For Cluster creation i created a service 
`dataproc-cluster-manager@poc.iam.gserviceaccount.com` with roles   "DataProc Editor" and "Service Account User" . Another Service account `dataproc-cluster-executor@poc.iam.gserviceaccount.com` with role "DataProc Worker".  I could able to create the cluster and run a job with "dataproc-cluster-manager@poc.iam.gserviceaccount.com" . I am also using custom image as well and every thing worked without any issue.

Comment: Great to hear, thanks for the update! I'll also update the answer to better organize the troubleshooting steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there are various features relevant here such as specifying a custom service account for the identity of the cluster and using custom images, some steps can be done to narrow down where the main issue might be:

1. Check whether *any* access-controlled API call works for the service account given broad permissions like `Project Viewer`, for example, and trying `gcloud compute instances list`, `gcloud compute regions list`, and `gcloud dataproc clusters list` - this will narrow down if it's something about Dataproc-specific roles or if the service-account itself is not working for some reason.
2. If it appears to work for other APIs but not Dataproc APIs, try the [Policy Troubleshooter tool](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/troubleshooting-access) tool until you can get basic "viewer" types of requests working with the Dataproc API
3. If a "default" Dataproc cluster can be created but one with custom options fails, you may need to add additional permissions, such as `Service Account User` for a specified cluster identity service-account, `Compute Network User` for cross-project networks, `Compute Image User` for cross-project custom images, or `Storage Object Creator` for cross-project or custom GCS configbuckets. Generally, errors on these types of permissions are expected to provide detailed error messages from the Dataproc API, compared to basic "front-door" access errors described in #1 which might have more generic error messages like you saw ("Not authorized to requested resource").

Other things to check include making sure you applied the role memberships to the correct resource (in this case, the project itself), rather than on the service account, since that list of roles should contain everything you need. Check:

```
gcloud projects get-iam-policy $PROJECT
```

To make sure your list of all those roles actually appears there with `members:` listing your service account. You should *not* expect the things like `Dataproc Editor`, etc to appear on the service-account's resource policy itself, as in:

```
gcloud iam service-accounts get-iam-policy $SERVICE_ACCOUNT
```

should return an empty response with only an `etag:` field.

When using custom service accounts, it's also important to understand the distinctions between the different roles involved.

One thing to first clarify is that the Dataproc "worker" and the Dataproc creator/user are not the generally the same identity, even though they can be. So if you intend for the service account to be used to *create* Dataproc clusters, `Dataproc Editor` is correct, but if you also intend to make the cluster itself take on the identity of the service account, you need to grant the service account the `Dataproc Worker` role as well: https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/iam/dataproc-principals

In this vein, if you're trying to use a service account to create a cluster that then acts as a specified service account, even if the specified account is "itself", you need to grant the `Service Account User` role to your service account, either at the project level (if you are okay granting it broad actAs permissions in the project) or just on the single service account.

Since you appear to be using a custom image, assuming you followed the advanced instructions for [creating a Dataproc custom image](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/guides/dataproc-images) you may also have to grant your service account the [Compute Image User role](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/managing-access-custom-images#share-images-between-organization).

In addition to that, if using an image in a different project you may need to check the service account of the form [service-[project-number]@dataproc-accounts.iam.gserviceaccount.com](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/iam/iam#service_accounts) and if your project was created before ~Sept 2019, also the legacy `[project-number]@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com` service account. Those would need to be granted the `Compute Image user role` on the images or the project holding those images. For same-project images, the existing `Dataproc Service Agent` role *should* already include the instanceAdmin permission that includes the image user role.

Comment: It seems that `[project-number]@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com` has to have access to `Compute Image user role` if you are planning to use preemptibile machines.  In absence of  this role these preemptible machines fails to be spin.